# Closing Forms in Windows Form App?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, FormA and FormB.

FormA has two buttons, one to open FormB and one to exit.
FormB has one button, to close FormB and reopen FormA.

My code goes like this:

```
public class FormA
{
    private void btnOpenformB_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FormB B = new FormB();
        this.Hide();
        B.Show();
    }
    private void btnExit_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

public class FormB
{
    private void btnReopenA_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FormA A = new FormA();
        this.Close();
        A.Show();
    }
}
```

My problem is when I click the button on FormB to reopen FormA, and when I click the exit button on FormA, it doesn't stop debugging. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: With `FormA A = new FormA();` you're creating a new form, when you do `A.Show();` you're not showing FormA that you have hidden (`this.Hide();`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class FormA {
  private void btnOpenformB_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    FormB B = new FormB();
    this.Hide();
    B.Show(this);//Note we pass in the Owner here
  }
  private void btnExit_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    this.Close();
  }
}

public class FormB {
  private void btnReopenA_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    if(Owner!=null) Owner.Show();
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open second form in dialog mode:

```
this.Hide();
B.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

lan, the problem with your code is that you don't return to the old `formA` when you press `btnReopenA` in `formB`, instead you open a new `formA`.

an elegant way to avoid that will be to register to the `FormClosing` event

```
private void btnOpenformB_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FormB B = new FormB();
    B.FormClosing += b_FormClosing;
    this.Hide();
    B.Show();
}

  void b_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
     Show();
  }
```

or, if you don't want to deal with events you can do this:

```
public partial class FormB : Form
{
  private Form _frm;
  public FormB(Form frm)
  {
     _frm = frm;
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void btnReopenA_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
       if(_frm!=null) _frm.Show();
       this.Close();
  }
}
```

and when creating `formB`:

```
private void btnOpenformB_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FormB B = new FormB(this);
    this.Hide();
    B.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is when I click the button on FormB to reopen FormA, and
>   when I click the exit button on FormA, it doesn't stop debugging.

This is because you opened another instance of `FormA` form your `FromB`

> What should I do?

You need to get a reference of `FormA` in `FormB` and `Show` that instead.

> How do i do it?

```
    public class FormA
    {
        private void btnOpenformB_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            FormB B = new FormB();
            B.Closed+=OnFromBClosed; //Add this to handle FromB Closed event
            this.Hide();
            B.Show();
        }
        private void btnExit_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

       //Show FormA again when FromB is closed
        protected void OnFromBClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }

    }

public class FormB
{
    private void btnReopenA_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       // FormA A = new FormA(); remove this.
        this.Close();
       // A.Show();  and remove this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.OpenForms[] collection:
Application.OpenForms["FormA"].Show()